# SQL Relation MORE on MORE

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a question about this relation betweed SpelerTeam and Toernooi, i get a error, can someone help me with it all the other relations do work:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 There are no primary or candidate
>   keys in the referenced table 'SpelerTeam' that match the referencing
>   column list in the foreign key 'FK__Toernooi__team__1A14E395'. Msg
>   1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 Could not create constraint. See
>   previous errors.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LoginGegevens
(
    Username                varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
    Wachtwoord              varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
    LoginDatum              date NOT NULL, 
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.NawGegevensKind
(
    KindSpeler              varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    NawKind             varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.NawGegevensProfspeler
(
    Profspeler          varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    NawProfspeler           varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.SpelerTeam
(
    Team                int  NOT NULL, 
    Kindspeler          varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
    Profspeler          varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Toernooi
(
    team         int NOT NULL,
    score        int NOT NULL,
    games        int NOT NULL,
    rondes       int NOT NULL,
)
-- primary keys 
ALTER TABLE LoginGegevens
ADD primary KEY (Username)

ALTER TABLE NawGegevensKind
ADD primary KEY (KindSpeler)

ALTER TABLE NawGegevensProfspeler
ADD primary KEY (ProfSpeler)

ALTER TABLE SpelerTeam
ADD primary KEY (Team,KindSpeler,ProfSpeler)

ALTER TABLE Toernooi
ADD primary KEY (Team,Rondes,Games)

-- relation
ALTER TABLE SpelerTeam
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Kindspeler)
REFERENCES NawGegevensKind(Kindspeler);

ALTER TABLE SpelerTeam 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Profspeler) 
REFERENCES NawGegevensProfspeler(Profspeler);

ALTER TABLE Toernooi 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Team) 
REFERENCES SpelerTeam(Team);
```

Comment: I think your question is regarding SQL-Server not mysql?

Comment: Don't confuse foreign key constraints with relations or relationships. A relation is a mathematical structure used in logical data modeling, relations are represented by tables. Relationships (in the entity-relationship model) map to relations, i.e. tables, though entity relations and relationship relations can be combined if they have the same determinant. Foreign key constraints just enforce that the values in one column (or set of columns) is a subset of another column (or set of columns). They don't relate rows, rows are associated based on shared values or any other predicate function.

Answer (score 2):

The Primary Key of `SpelerTeam` is `Team,KindSpeler,ProfSpeler`.

That means that any foreign key that references that table has to reference all three of those columns.   You can't create a foreign key that uses only `team`.

Answer (score 0):

You need an index on a colum so that it can be referenced as a foreign key efficiently. Add an index on `SpelerTeam.Team` and on all other columns with the same problem. Try `CREATE INDEX IX_SpelerTeam_Team_Team ON SpelerTeam (Team);`

Comment: 'CREATE INDEX Team_Connectie1
ON SpelerTeam (Team,KindSpeler,ProfSpeler); 

CREATE INDEX Team_Connectie2
ON Toernooi (Team,Rondes,Games); '

Comment: @Richard B, you need to create index on Team, not whole primary key

Comment: CREATE INDEX Team_Connectie1
ON SpelerTeam (Team);

Answer (score 0):

Add below after all tables have been created:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SpelerTeam_Team  
ON dbo.SpelerTeam (Team); 
GO
```

As it was pointed in another answer you cannot reference to non unique column, to make column unique you can make this column primary key or create index for this column. 
It is not enough that your "Team" column is part of composite key.

Comment: This doesn't work because there is already a clustered index (primary) on the table.

Comment: answer edited, change to nonclustered, clustered has been created while primary key creation

Comment: did you add this line after tables creation (including GO), before adding constraints?